# Accessing iCloud Drive files from app

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud-drive

I want to have iCloud support in my app where I can store and get PDF files.
My question is "How to access iCloud drive file without using `UIDocumentPickerViewController`". Actually I want to have custom files list in my app.

I tried this code

```
- (void) getAllFilesIniCloud
{
    queryData = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    [queryData setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryAccessibleUbiquitousExternalDocumentsScope]];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K like '*.'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
    [queryData setPredicate:pred];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:)
                                                 name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                               object:queryData];
    [queryData startQuery];
}

- (void)queryDidFinishGathering:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSMetadataQuery *pQuery = [notification object];
    [pQuery disableUpdates];
    [pQuery stopQuery];
    [pFilesArray removeAllObjects];
    for (NSMetadataItem *item in [query results])
    {
        NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        NSString * name = url.lastPathComponent;

        if ([[name pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pdf"] || [[name pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"PDF"])
        {
            NSString *fileName = [url.absoluteString lastPathComponent];

            if (url && ![pFilesArray containsObject:fileName])
            {
                [pFilesArray addObject:fileName];
            }

        }
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:pQuery];

    queryData = nil;
    [pTableView reloadData];
}
```

and also tried the scope

```
NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope
NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope
NSMetadataQueryAccessibleUbiquitousExternalDocumentsScope
```

I know this code working fine for app directory in iCloud. But if user store file in iCloud in Mac or through web then my app should also enable to access this file.

Comment: you can not get list of files and make custom view ..,if you want to show list of  files you need to use UIDocumentPickerViewController...or else you can use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore

Answer (score -5):

I had the same problem , please go through  this thread to clarify on iCloud
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/283726#Comment_283726

Comment: This link needs a Xamarin login.