# How to get file list in iCloud Drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud-drive

I am implementing iCloud Drive in iOS app(objective c)

I want to know how to get file list in root folder or specific folder.

Comment: Usually there's very little information regarding this in Apple's documentation. Just visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622062/how-do-i-tell-ios-to-download-a-file-from-icloud-drive-and-get-progress-feedback)

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039718/accessing-icloud-drive-files-from-app